# get clicked related video's url in youtube_player_iframe

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, youtube-api

I'm using [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe) in my flutter app. I want to know when a user click on a related video that appear after the end of the current video and get that video's url or id.

Here's my code if needed:

The controller

```
late YoutubePlayerController videoPlayerController = YoutubePlayerController(
    initialVideoId: videoId,
    params: YoutubePlayerParams(
      autoPlay: false,
      loop: false,
      mute: false,
      showControls: true,
      showFullscreenButton: true,
      privacyEnhanced: true,
    ),
  );
```

The widget

```
YoutubePlayerIFrame(
 controller: videoPlayerController,
 aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
),
```

I looked into the docs but couldn't find what I wanted.